# In NestJS how to get request object in service without injecting request from controller

Tags: request, nestjs

How can I inject the request or the execution context in a service without the help of controller without any performance issues?

Answer (score 2):

The docs make it very clear that to pass the request to a service you can use a `REQUEST` scoped service with `@Inject(REQUEST)` or you can get the request in the controller via `@Req()` and pass that to the service method.

There is [nestjs-cls](https://github.com/Papooch/nestjs-cls) which may be helpful as well, but generally, you either pass it on or you take the performance hit for REQUEST scoping the provider.

Comment: Does node-execution-context(https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-execution-context) in any way favour in performance than the proposed solution ? Please let me know I'm new to this thing

Comment: No clue, not a package I'm aware of  nor one I've used